# Wordpress breaking only in IE9

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

I was recently hired by a new company and one of my duties is upkeep on old sites. It's recently been brought to my attention that one of Wordpresses is broken in IE9.

www.nexoslatinos.com

I've tried deactivating all plugins, no fix.

I've tried switching to default themes, even they appear broken.

I've opened the developer tools in IE9 and it's rendering the site in what it calls "Quirks Mode"??

The theme is for the most part identical to the theme found in the spanish translation version:
www.nexoslatinos.com/espanol 
which is rendering fine in IE9. When taking the Spanish translation theme and applying it to the first wordpress, it breaks. The two themes also run identical plugins. They are however, different wordpress installations.

When I view the source for the page, I am getting a strange line of code before the doctype:

```
<!--331c6883dd6010864b7ead130be77cd5-->
```

Could this be throwing off IE9? I haven't been able to locate the code's origin, but it stuck out when reviewing the site in my initial troubleshooting.

The code for the theme is a bit of a mess and isn't valid, but despite that is displaying fine in Chrome, FF, and Safari.

Thoughts? Insights?

Comment: Anything before the doctype will absolutely cause problems. You'll have to keep looking for the source of that nonsense comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds to me like it could be a file encoding issue. I would recommend checking to make sure all of the php files that make up the theme as well as all Wordpress core files that might have been modified are UTF-8. You can do that in your code editor, or by checking each file here: http://people.w3.org/rishida/utils/bomtester/

A quicker way to narrow down the scope of potentially problematic files might be to create a clean dummy Wordpress installation and activate the seemingly problematic theme. If the problem is still there, it's got to be a problem with one of your theme files. If it's not there, I suspect that there might have been some unsound edits made to the Wordpress core files.

Comment: I used the bomtester yesterday, as that was the first thing I found when people were complaining about characters appearing before the doctype, but the tool isn't picking anything up.

Answer (score 4):

That comment (not code) is  an MD5 hash of "**pizda**" -- which is a eastern european pejorative meaning vagina in various languages.  You can see this http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pizda for ethnological details.

Check your WP theme for code fragments that might look suspicious. If it's not there, check apache configuration for a site-wide server-side include (SSI).

Don't mean to alarm you as I didn't look at the site, but I would check files, database for malware, whether server-side, client side, or both.  Not 100% sure, but additionally there is a pizda kernel exploit - you may want to have the hosting machines checked.

Comment: Clarification: I pulled up the site code with lynx, but didn't look at the site with an actual browser.

Comment: This is great advice. Just to add to it so you know for the future, anything before the doctype will force IE to render in quirks mode. You can read more about that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Comment: I'm not seeing anything on my end that would raise any red flags. I got rid of two htaccess files that seemed a bit off upon viewing, but nothing else.

As for apache configuration, the site is hosted elsewhere, is that something that the host would have to check out or can I do it from my end?

Comment: I found the culprit! There was an odd bit of code in the file "wp-blog-header.php" that was causing the comment to appear before the doctype and send ie9 into quirks mode. I isolated and deleted the code, and it appears as if everything is now correct! Thanks for all the great comments and thoughts!